# How can I remove time in other locations from the Unity date indicator menu?

Tags: unity, indicator, 16.10, time, date

I un-ticked "Time in auto-detected location" as well as "Time in other locations". However, the time of my current (I assume auto-detected location) is still being shown in the time & date indicator menu.

**How can I remove the red-highlighted entry from the menu (Screenshot 3)?**

**Screenshot 1:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 3:**

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: hmm, I thought I had it figured out but it seems it always puts your autodetected time there.

Comment: I was hoping for some `gsettings` to remove it...